# How to pass any type of object as input parameter with only 1 method

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I've a WCF service with one method which will be called from multiple web API controllers like in the below code.

```
    public string Print(PdfPrinterRequest _request)
    {
        PdfPrinterService.PdfPrinterClient _Client = new PdfPrinterService.PdfPrinterClient();
        PdfPrinterResponse _response = new PdfPrinterResponse();
        return _Client.Print(_request.Document, out _pdfResponse);
    }
```

PdfPrinterRequest(Document class) is the entity which I'm passing to get the response message from WCF service.Currently the document class holds few properties(REquest Header). I would like to call the same Print method from other API and pass type 'Customer' to WCF service. How can i achieve this? Can anyone please suggest me the correct implementation?

Below is my WCF service code,

```
   public class PdfPrinterService : IPdfPrinter
   {
      public PdfPrinterResponse Print(PdfPrinterRequest request)
      {
        return PdfPrinterFacade.PrintPdf(request);
      }
   }

   public static PdfPrinterResponse PrintPdf(PdfPrinterRequest request)
    {
        PdfPrinterResponse response = new PdfPrinterResponse();
        //Process the request and send back the response message
    }

    [MessageContract]
    public class PdfPrinterRequest
    {
    private Document _document;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Document Document
    {
        get { return _document; }
        set { _document = value; }
    }
   }
```

How to pass a dynamic class object as a parameter in place of PdfPrinterRequest which is no bound to only one type(Document)? Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: Try to use method overloads if that is possible.

Comment: Do you have a common method in all objects like `GetRepsonse()`, or at least can you change them to have such a common method ?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy , I can have overloads, But dont know how many methods i end up with, Rather i would like to have one method to accept any type of class object. Thanks

Comment: @user3185569 : I'm maintaing Request and Response objects where Request will hold all the input parameters and Response is common for all Requests with a MEssage and Info as return types.

Comment: @PuliganP In this case you need to have a common base class `Foo` for all request classes with certain functionality you need to process the request. `PdfPrinterRequest` would then be extending `Foo`.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, Can you please post an example.. Tahnks

Comment: @PuliganP Sadly using a base class will not work according to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1321278/3936440, please have a look at the first answer refering to the `MessageContract` issue.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, So, I need to have overlod methods with different Requests? Right

Comment: Any example please to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning:** The `NetDataContractSerializer` poses a significant [security risk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) and should be avoided.

---

If this service does not need to be interoperable, you can switch to `NetDataContractSerializer`, which uses full .NET type information, and is able to serialize many more types (but not *any* type - that's impossible).
Grab the `UseNetDataContractSerializerAttribute` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779442/276083) and apply like so:

```
[UseNetDataContractSerializer]
public class PdfPrinterService : IPdfPrinter
{
   public PdfPrinterResponse Print(PdfPrinterRequest request)
   {
     return PdfPrinterFacade.PrintPdf(request);
   }
}

[MessageContract]
public class PdfPrinterRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public object Document { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In the above Print method, I'm now passing fixed type 'PdfPrinterRequest', Rather i would like to pass any type of Request. Please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Ok, I've changed MessageContracts to DataContract and I removed Document class property from the PdfPrinterRequest class and put request related properties. Can you quote the full example here?

Comment: I just need to pass a dynamic Type to Print method as input parameter and execute some business logic based on the passed type and return data.